# string in a file as a variable

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a conf file content like below.

**file.conf:**

```
key="name"
value="pswd"
```

Now I want write a script to having two variable like above

**script.sh**

```
key="name"      #key as variable
value="pswd"    #value as variable
```

Comment: `. /path/to/file.conf` (if the file is not under your control, then you'll want to sanitize it though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just source the file inside the script:

```
. /path/to/file.conf
```

But notice, the `.conf` file must have a valid `sh` syntax, because `.` interprets the content of the given file as `sh` code.

(`.` is the POSIX/portable command for Bourne-like shells. For `(t)csh` shells, use `source` instead. `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh` support both though with subtle differences for some)

Comment: It's working for bash. I mainly looking for shell script (`#!/bin/sh`). It is saying `source not found`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. For `bin/sh`, we just need to `source` with a `.`